# onUpdate called when Configuration Activity is launched

Tags: java, android, android-widget

According to the App Widgets documentation, `onUpdate` method should not be called if a Configuration Activity has been declared.

Still it is being called when the configuration activity is launched...

How do I prevent it from being called and call it only when the configuration activity has been closed with `RESULT_OK` code.

Thank you upfront.

Answer (score 0):

I'm never too certain about what methods are called on you AppWidget, because some of the logic is up to the developer of the launcher application, not to the Android OS itself. So this differs quite a lot between Launchers (Samsung, Google, HTC, KK etc.) Your widget should be prepared to degrade in a way acceptable for the user.

Take a look at AppWidgetProvider source:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/android-cts-4.2_r1/core/java/android/appwidget/AppWidgetProvider.java

It extends BroadcastReceiver, so you can add extra logic to onReceive() to avoid calling onUpdate() if your configuration activity hasn't been closed yet.

You can use SharedPreferences to pass this information.